# PHP How to ZIP multiple files located in different paths?

Tags: php, zip

I have 16631 files hosted in a webserver, 2719 of them are text files that contains a list of specific files located on the server.

Using PHP, is possible to create a ZIP for each text file?
could be the text file name as ZIP file name?

I want to keep the same directory structure in the ZIP file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

Comment: If you don't need any particular folder structure, I would recommend copying each file into the temp directory and then create the zip file from there.

Comment: creating 2719 zip files manually is a bit complicated, im looking for a function or script to make it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the suggestion from Jeff Hines, you could use the [`ZipArchive`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class to create the zip.

In Pseudo code

1. Get List of Text Files in your folder
2. Read Text file and get list of files to add to zip
3. Using ZipArchive add each listed file to your new zip file.
4. Write flag to specify you've done this file.

You might need to run it on 10 files at a time since it may time out.